# Disable cURL reading

Tags: php, curl

Some one is reading my page through cURL.
How can I disable its access to my page through cURL ?
He is using this method to read my page

```
function ajax(){
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "../ajaxupdate.php",
data: { link: "58699768" }
}).success(function( msg ) {
$('#postcontent').html( msg );
ajax();
});
}
ajax();
```

Comment: You are reading your own page as the above code uses relative paths. Also, how can you use curl in javascript as per your question?

Comment: This is not my script. read question in full

Comment: Then it's really more confusing. How come this script is using relative paths to your script `../ajaxupdate.php`. This means this is hosted on the same server as your `page`. Also, suppose this is somebody else's script as you say, how are you able to determine the exact the code the user is using to access your page? Your question and code don't complement each other.

Answer (score 0):

It would be very difficult cause cURL offers tons of options and therefore may bypass pretty much any security, unless you ask for captcha or login/password with active cookies and sessions. Two things you could do is:
1.Block the ip in any way you like-in the script or using iptables.
2.Kill the script when you see his user agent so he/she gets nothing.

But as I said-there are millions of ways to bypass those-proxies, switching user agents and anything in between.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the connection of the annoying client by checking `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`.

If it contains the string `curl` just return a blank page.

E.g.

```
if (preg_match('/curl/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) 
    return;
```

Obviously it is not a 100% safe method since `curl` can set a custom `User-Agent` into HTTP headers.

Comment: This can be bypassed. I want secure method

Comment: Sorry... i think a 100% secure method doesn't exists since curl can alter any parameter of http headers